# python Tkinter Bind label to loop event

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hi Im trying to get a label in tkinter to show each item at a time as it loops through a list. My code only shows the last element in label once loop is complete. Shell works fine. Thanks

```
 from Tkinter import*
 import tkMessageBox
 import time
 top = Tk()
 top.geometry("500x500+100+200")

 w =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1620]
 def bello():
     for pp in w :
         print(pp)
         myLabel = Label(top, text=pp).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='e')
         time.sleep(1)

 B1 = Button(top, text = "Say Hello", command = bello)
 B1.place(x=50, y=50)
 top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you making 16 new Labels on top of each other each time `bello` is called? Just make 1 label and in `bello` update it with the new text.  BTW, it's not a good idea to use `time.sleep` in Tkinter programs, take a look at the `widget.after` method. Also, the `.grid` method returns `None`, so `myLabel = Label(top, text=pp).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='e')` sets `myLabel` to `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `update()` method to update the GUI everytime a new value from the loop is displayed:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time


top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500+100+200")

w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1620]


def bello():
    for pp in w:
        print(pp)
        Label(top, text=pp).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='e')

        time.sleep(1)
        top.update() #refreshes top before looping to the next element


B1 = Button(top, text="Say Hello", command=bello)
B1.place(x=50, y=50)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much such a teeny tiny option grounding me.

Comment: Indeed.Glad it helped!